# Where can I find create_tables.sql for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When logging into phpMyAdmin I receive the following warning:

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated.

I am attempting phpMyAdmin's suggested remedy here: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration

I tried finding create_tables.sql, like this...

```
find / -name 'create_tables.sql'
```

I even tried finding all .sql files, like this...

```
find / -iname '*.sql'
```

...but it wasn't one of the files found.

Is there somewhere I can download this file?

Comment: the very page you linked to has the download options, and suggests the file location- how much more help can be provided?

Comment: at the top of the page you linked to are the distributions options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links at the top of the documentation page were useless.

Go to http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php
Download one of the packages, and in the root you will find the ./sql/create_tables.sql file that the documentation was referencing.

It also turns out the `create_tables.sql` file that is downloadable from the link above is missing one of the tables `pma__designer_coords`

To add the missing table, run the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__designer_coords` (
    `db_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `table_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `x` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `y` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `v` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `h` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Get it together phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Why not create a pull request? https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tree/master/sql

Comment: That would be fine too. At the time, this post was more to address that multiple places in their own documentation or files there were inconsistencies. I even tried reaching out, but they didn't seem to care.